# Determine Cache Invalidation criteria

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I am saving MySQL query results using memcached.

I have two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id = 1

SELECT * FROM groups WHERE user_group = 23
```

The first query returns only 1 record while second query return multiple records.

My question is that in case of first query, we can easily invalidate cache record when someone has updated that record. But what criteria should be used for cache to become invalid when any of the record is updated in case of second query?

**UPDATE**

A user can have many groups created. I am saving all the groups for a user in cache. Like cache record with ID "group1" will have data for just single group. But cache record with "usegroup23" will have 100s of groups. So if user changes the name of one of his groups, I think there is no way to invalidate the cache record. But the only way would be to update the name of that group in "usergroup23" cache record.

Comment: so group_id is an PRIMARY key, it is a ID of group, and user_group is a owner_id, id of user who created that group, is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. There are two approaches :

a) Keeping TTL very short, like 15s, 1minute and not invalidating cache at all. Users will see changes with small delay. It's good for things that don't have to be super fresh everytime. You shouldn't use that approach for things like changing user information. User should see changes right after submitting the form, If he doesn't see changes, he will submit form again, and again and again, then he will get annoyed and leave your application and never comeback.

b) When you're modifying an element in your db then you should always invalidate all cache entries for that element. You're trying to keep good long TTL (1hr, 1 day) and when you're changing element A you should invalidated all places where you keep data about your element.
Instead of keeping in cache "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ..." I would suggest you to keep only set of ID's.

As an example you should have something like

`SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id = $ID`, and second one `SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE user_group = $OTHER_ID`

Then when you do edit group `group_id=1` you have to only invalidate cache for `group_id=1` details and invalidate the `user_group=$id` cache if you changed the user_group property.

In cache try to keep only sets of id's and information about single objects. Of course it depends on case and sometimes you have to keep more than ID's, but this is the safest approach.

Comment: Thank piotr. I have updated my question. Can you please post your comments?